# Modify default view for My Sites OneDrive document library in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, document-library, view, mysites

With SharePoint 2013 in your My Sites OneDrive document library (username/Documents/) the default view All (username/Documents/Forms/All.aspx) cannot be modified or changed to a custom view by the user. For example in the ribbon bar the Modify View command is disabled and in the view selector there is no Modify View command when the All view is current. Also in a custom view edit page there is no option "Make this the default view".

Whereas all these things are possible in another document library in My Sites and in a collaboration site document library.

Is it possible some other way, eg for the farm admin or via code, to modify the My Sites OneDrive document library default view?

For example, if we want all users to have some additional columns in this view.